# import a DB with RSQLite

Tags: sqlite, r

My question is the following :
I have a file "table.sql" corresponding to one table. I want to use it in R with RSQLite. Is it possible to import the table to work with or should I use a connection to a MySQL or PostgreSQL server instead ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is in `table.sql`?  Is it a `CREATE TABLE` statement?  Please provide more detail (e.g., the contents of that file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can if the file is indeed a Sqlite database so please try installing the `RSQLite` package and study the examples.

```
install.packages('RSQLite')
library('RSQLite')
```